# Converting a Surface back to Pixbuf

Tags: c#, mono, cairo, gdk

I have the following code to draw on a `Pixbuf`:

```
private Pixbuf drawOnPixbuf(Pixbuf original)
{
    Surface surface = new ImageSurface(Format.Argb32, original.Width, original.Height);
    Context ctx = new Context(surface);
    CairoHelper.SetSourcePixbuf(ctx, original, 0, 0);

    // Draw on the surface here. Not shown since not relevant. 

    // Here, I want to convert the surface back to pixbuf.
    Pixbuf finishedPixbuf = ...;

    ctx.GetTarget().Dispose();
    ctx.Dispose();

    return finishedPixbuf;
}
```

I can't find out how to convert the `Surface` back to `Pixbuf`.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for seems to be part of Gdk:

```
cairo_surface_t *
gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf (const GdkPixbuf *pixbuf,
                                      int scale,
                                      GdkWindow *for_window);
```

https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Cairo-Interaction.html#gdk-cairo-surface-create-from-pixbuf

Specifically, `gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf(pixbuf, 1, NULL)` should do what you want. (Sorry, I do not know how to express this in C#.)

Comment: What is the Gtk/Gdk 4.0 way to do this? This function got removed. I really hate that the Gtk people do deprecate but never add enough documentation about how to port it to the new way of things.